# Can values of array of pointers to strings be overwriten?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

For example:

```
char* p[10];
char* x = "string"
char* y = "char"
int main{

    fun1(){
       for (i = 0; i<10;i++ ){
             p[i]=x;
       }
    }

    fun2(){
       for (i = 0; i<10;i++ ){
             p[i]= y;
       }
     }
}
```

Will the value that is pointed by the pointer overwritten? Or will be saved in the different adress.

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo don't derail the post to debate C and java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the several syntax and other errors, yes, the pointers in an array `p` declared with `char *p[10]` may be modified. This simply changes them to point to different places.

Comment: So the values in the first will remain?

Comment: @Sansara: Changing the pointers will not change the data at the places they point to. It merely changes the pointers.

Comment: So what is the best way to free the space that previous value was saved in?

Comment: @Sansara: String literals are permanent; they exist for the lifetime of your program. You cannot free them. If the pointers had pointed to dynamically allocated space (as with `malloc`, `realloc`, or `calloc`), then you should free the space with `free`.